# React Router components getting unmount on route change

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux, react-router

I creating a SPA with React + Redux, where I am using react-route.
I am facing one issue that whenever I am switching my routes like /about, /contact, /list.. **each time components gets unmount**.

So, I would need to know that is this a expected behavior or I am doing something wrong. Because in some component I am making an ajax call to get data and if component gets unmounted and user comes back again... it makes ajax call again even if data is already available in store.

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
</Route>
```

Comment: "is this a expected behavior". Yes. If you change the route, the current route component gets unmount and new route component is mounted.

Comment: Is there any way to stop this. Actually I don't need to unmount the component every time. Because of unnecessary ajax hits. 
Also is this correct approach to stop un-mounting of the components?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each time you navigate to a route the old component is removed, the new component is loaded and gets populated with the store values (with redux's connect).

The data will always be available in the store, so you dont need to fire new ajax requests when a component unload and reload again.

And, if you still want components to be available all the time, then you can use a single route and show and hide components from your main component using a navigation menu or tabs.. but depending on the number of components the DOM can get pretty heavy.

Comment: I completely agree what you have said, but my problem is I am making ajax (from componentWillMount or componentDidMount) call to get data from component it self, and if a component will get unmount and mount again its lifecycle methods will get fired..

Comment: You can keep that in the componentDidMount, but add a condition to not dispatch the loadAll action, if the data is already loaded before. so it will be loaded only the first time that component is mounted